# iOS - How to neglect dequed cell after change in UItableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple tableView in which i change the cell whenever i click it in the function like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   [self shuftleCellExpansion:indexPath.row];

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];

}
```

**Second Functions:**

```
-(BOOL) shuftleCellExpansion:(int) indexP
{
    if([opendedCells containsIndex:indexP])
    {
        [opendedCells removeIndex:indexP];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [opendedCells addIndex:indexP];
        return YES;
    }

}
```

Cell for index Function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if([self isCellInExpandedList:indexPath.row])
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell is in Expanded State %hhd for Index Path %ld",[self isCellInExpandedList:indexPath.row], (long)indexPath.row);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"poCell"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"poCell"];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         [cell imageView].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someicon.png"];
               return cell;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"poCell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"poCell"];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     return cell;
}
```

No the issue is that when ever i change a specific cell and then scroll it the cell at after the specific cells (i.e. after total visible cells) i see the same changed cell .

**What is the efficient way to get Rid of this?**

Comment: What is the change you are making? What is in `shuftleCellExpansion`? What is showing incorrectly? Also, why are you running deselectCell? Why not just set the cell selection style to none?

Comment: Your issue is because of using dequed cell, Tableview uses dequed cell when it is not visible. Can you paste code for cellForRowAtIndexPath: for more help?

Comment: @Fogmeister Question Updated

Comment: By the way NSArray has arrayWithObject:, to have an array of one object. Or use @[object], for shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Every cell which go off the screen goes to reuse pool (mostly all data are erase) and if you scroll back the cell is populated in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method again.

You need to change the data source if you want to keep the changes.
In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: you need to also make the changes in the array (I assume you use array to read the data from in cellForRowAtIndexPath:) you use in cellForRowAtIndexPath: to populate cell.

Hope this help.

// EXTENDED

To make it work you need to amend shuftleCellExpansion: method. In opendedCells you swap the indexes, I believe it reflect the changes in table view. In the same method you have to reflect the changes for searchResults array as well (swap the object as you did for opendedCells).

Comment: @user2043155 see extended post.